# Join first table with latest record of second table

Tags: sql-server

I have table `Product` and table `Sales`

I `Product` table I have list of product with primary key `prodId` and in `Sales` table I have total sales for that product.

I want to get data from table `Product` by joining it with `Sales` table's latest record (using `SalesDate` column).

`Sales` table may contain 0 to n number of records for particular product.

I know I can do it using sub-query but I need to avoid one due to performance overhead. I also don't want to use `max` function as it will require me to mentions lots f column in group by.

Can I do this with simple join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ROW_NUMBER feature. like this

```
;with cte
as
(
    select
        SeqNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY SalesDate DESC),
        *
        FROM Sales
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM Product p
        LEFT JOIN cte
         ON p.ProducId = cte.ProductId AND cte.SeqNo = 1
```